# Relation between Hilbert space norm and trace operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator\tr{tr}$I am currently reading a paper where I encountered an equation that doesn't make sense to me.
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $x\in H$. The equation that is used is:
$$\lVert x\rVert_H^2 = \tr(xx^*)$$
where $\tr$ denotes the trace operator and $x^*$ the adjoint of x.
I am unsure how to interpret this, as I don't know any definition for an adjoint of a Hilbert space element, only of operators on $H$.

This is clearly supposed to be a generalization of the equation for $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\lVert x\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n}^2 = \tr(xx^t)$$

Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: I'm guessing they mean $x^*: v \in H \mapsto \langle x , v \rangle$. You can map $H \otimes H^* \to \operatorname{End}(H)$ by sending the simple tensors $x \otimes \varphi \mapsto [v \mapsto \varphi(v) x]$; you can then take the trace of $x \otimes x^*$ because it is a trace class operator, and its trace happens to be exactly $\langle x , x \rangle = \lvert x \rvert^2$.

Comment: You could improve this question by saying what the "paper" is which you are reading, or even better, give a link.  I find that it's often very hard to make sense of a snippet of Mathematics out of context, while put into context, it can often be quite easy to work out (or take an educated guess) as to what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

Elements of a Hilbert space are routinely seen as linear operators via the Riesz Representation Theorem. That is, if $x\in H$ then $x^* :H\to\mathbb C$ is the linear functional $x^*y=\langle y,x\rangle$. This is coherent with the finite-dimensional picture where this would be literally the matrix product $x^*y$.

Then $zx^*$ (often denoted $z\otimes x$) is the rank-one operator $zx^*(y)=\langle y,x\rangle z$. The $zx^*$ notation has the advantage that it correctly captures the fact that the $x$ conjugates scalars, in the sense that $(\alpha a)\otimes(\beta x)=\alpha\overline\beta\,(z\otimes x)$. The notation is also coherent with $x^*y=\langle y,x\rangle$. So one can correctly write $$(zx^*)y=z (x^*y)=\langle y,x\rangle\,a.$$ Incidentally, this exactly what physicists do with the bra-ket notation: $zx^*$ is precisely $|z\rangle\langle x|$.

It's an easy exercise that the operator norm of $zx^*$ is $\|zx^*\|=\|z\|\,\|x\|$. In particular, $\|xx^*\|=\|x\|^2$. If you calculate the trace using an orthonormal basis that contains $x/\|x\|$ it is clear that $$\operatorname{tr}(xx^*)=\Big\langle (xx^*)\frac x{\|x\|},\frac x{\|x\|}\Big\rangle=\|x\|^2.$$ Alternatively one can note that $\big(\frac x{\|x\|})(\frac x{\|x\|})^*$ is a rank-one projection and so it's trace is $1$.